# In Excel, is text zero or what?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of numbers that also contains the letter T. If I use a simple `IF(A1>0,...`, the letter T is treated as greater than zero and produces the "true" result. However, if I use `Countif(A1:A10, ">0"...`, then the T seems to treated as 0; it does not add to the count. Am I missing something? Is there a general rule about the handling of text when compared to numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following information is a product of my own experimentation.

The `COUNTIF` function is less forgiving of type mismatches than the `>` operator. It appears that `>` (and `<`), like Excel's sort feature, will always sort text as being greater than any number but never equal to any number, not  the character's ASCII code, not zero. For example, a column containing `5`, `A`, `7`, `C`, `B`, `2` will be sorted into `2`, `5`, `7`, `A`, `B`, `C` when you sort descending.

`COUNTIF`, however, requires that the two things being compared are of a similar type. If they aren't, it doesn't count them. By "similar" I mean things like comparing numbers to currency, which works as expected.

Don't be deceived - `COUNTIF` search strings starting with comparison operators like `>` don't have the same behavior as the actual operators. Notice that using `COUNTIF` to compare text with numbers in any way (whether it be `>`, `<`, or `=`) doesn't result in an addition to the total. Exception: the `<>` (not equal) operator always succeeds when the operands are of sufficiently different types. Similar results can be observed with dates and plain text.

So, no. Text is not treated as a zero, but the exact handling of it depends on what you're using.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Ben N, your reply answers my quesion. I could not find any MS documentation on this point. Thanks.